# Image from SQL Database to CImage

Tags: c++, sql

I'm struggling at the moment and hope that someone can help me.

I have to get an Image out of a SQL database  (like with SQLGetData) and than convert that data to a CImage so I can view it in my program.

Thanks for any help!

```
SQLGetData(m_Hstmt, col, SQL_C_BINARY, BinaryPtr, 0, &cbData)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. What didn't work? Please also read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be reduced to loading a `CImage` from a byte array, since that is what you get from `SQLGetData`.

You did not indicate whether you mean to use ATL or MFC, but in both cases it is a little bit awkward as there is no such thing as a public ::LoadFromBuffer function.

This answer should do:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6759701/1132334

It explains how to create a bitmap structure from a byte buffer and construct a CImage from there.

It is going to be tricky if you need to handle different picture formats. In this case, write the raw bytes to a memory mapped file and then use the `CImage::Load(IStream*)` overload.

**EDIT**: its all been done before... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14035492/1132334 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38710933/1132334

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the replies so far. Acoording to @dlatikay answer, this is my code so far. But I'm not sure about the types and somehow my Image stayes black (when I save it to file system)

heres my code so far.

```
SQLLEN    cbData;
CImage    image;

BYTE* imgBits;

    m_Rc = SQLGetData(m_Hstmt, 1, SQL_C_BINARY, imgBits, 0, &cbData);


    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(m_Rc))
    {
        width = 317;
        height = 159;

        BITMAPINFOHEADER bmInfohdr;
        // Create the header info
        bmInfohdr.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bmInfohdr.biWidth = width;
        bmInfohdr.biHeight = -height;
        bmInfohdr.biPlanes = 1;
        bmInfohdr.biBitCount = 8 * 8;
        bmInfohdr.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        bmInfohdr.biSizeImage = width*height * 8;
        bmInfohdr.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmInfohdr.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmInfohdr.biClrUsed = 0;
        bmInfohdr.biClrImportant = 0;

        BITMAPINFO bmInfo;
        bmInfo.bmiHeader = bmInfohdr;
        bmInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue = 255;

        // Allocate some memory and some pointers
        unsigned char * p24Img = new unsigned char[width*height * 3];
        BYTE *pTemp, *ptr;
        pTemp = (BYTE*)imgBits;
        ptr = p24Img;

        // Convert image from RGB to BGR
        for (DWORD index = 0; index < width*height; index++)
        {
            unsigned char r = *(pTemp++);
            unsigned char g = *(pTemp++);
            unsigned char b = *(pTemp++);

            *(ptr++) = b;
            *(ptr++) = g;
            *(ptr++) = r;
        }

        // Create the CImage
        image.Create(width, height, 8, NULL);
        image.Save(_T("c:\\temp\\image1.bmp")); // for testing
    }
```